# Change list in ComboBox2 based on selected value in ComboBox1

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following Excel spreadsheet:

```
              A                        B                               
1       Filter Selected 1       Filter Selected 2
2       Product A
3 
4       List of ComboBox1       List of ComboBox2
5       Product A               Brand A  =IF($A$2=$A$5,"Brand A","Brand B")
6       Product B               Brand A  =IF($A$2=$A$5,"Brand A","Brand B")
7       Product C               Brand A  =IF($A$2=$A$5,"Brand A","Brand B")
8
```

In range A5:A7 you can find a list that I use in the the `ComboBox1` within a UserForm. In range B5:B7 you can find a list that I use in the `ComboBox2` within the UserForm. Once the user selects a value in one of the ComboBoxes it gets typed into either cell A2 or cell B2.

As you can see for the list of `ComboBox2` I use an `IF`-Condition based on the selections of `ComboBox1` so if the user selects `Product A` in `CombobBox1` the list in range B5:B7 will be changed to `Brand A`.
However, this change is not immediately transferred to the `ComboBox2` so instead of `Brand A` it is still showing `Brand B` unless I re-open the UserForm.

The code for my UserForm is:

```
Sub UserForm_Activate()
    ComboBox1.List = Sheet1.Range("A5:A7").Value
    ComboBox2.List = Sheet1.Range("B5:B7").Value
    ComboBox1.Value = Sheet1.Range("A2")
    ComboBox2.Value = Sheet1.Range("B2")
End Sub

Sub ComboBox1_Change()
    Sheet1.Range("A2").Value = ComboBox1.Value
End Sub

Sub ComboBox2_Change()
    Sheet1.Range("B2").Value = ComboBox2.Value
End Sub

Sub UserForm_Close()
    Unload UserForm1
End Sub
```

What do I have to change in this code so the list in `ComboBox2` is immediately updated after a value is selected in `ComboBox1`?

Comment: Have you tried putting the list code in the change events?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `ComboBox1_Change` event try to calculate the sheet to make sure the values in the formulas are updated before you reload the list in `ComboBox2`.

```
Sub ComboBox1_Change()
    Sheet1.Range("A2").Value = ComboBox1.Value
    Sheet1.Calculate 'update formula values
    ComboBox2.List = Sheet1.Range("B5:B7").Value 'reload the values into the list
End Sub
```

Comment: Awesome. Thanks.